# Unique values from some column, DF pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

If I have some DataFrame:

```
A B
1 a
1 a
1 b 
1 c
1 c
1 d
2 a
2 b
2 b
2 d
```

I can use `groupby()` command and count the number of events from every unique line. But now, I don't want count all unique lines. I want just count how many unique values in column `B` correspond to some value in the column `A`. My output now should be

```
A UniqueValuesFromB
1 4
2 3
```

For this i did next code:

```
userNumber = []
items = []
for pos in df[column].unique():
        dfEvent = df[df[column] == pos]
        userNumber.append(len(numpy.unique(dfEvent[correspondingColumn])))
        items.append(pos)
```

And then I do new new DF from new lists... What is a better way to code this fragment. Specially, I feel I can use here the `groupby()` command or similar one. **Please, only pythonic way (or implementation of some pandas function) specially with the strong time performance improvement is asked.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using `value_counts`, the key here is to pass the level number to `count`:

```
In [32]:

df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(pd.value_counts).count(level=0)
Out[32]:
A
1    4
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Another variant:

```
In [48]:

df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.count(x.unique()))
Out[48]:
A
1    4
2    3
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: ok, I can combine the function `value_counts` and `groupby` through `apply` function. Thank you very much!

Comment: Very neat! However, applying `pd.value_counts` seems to be a little slower than aggregating using `unique` on my machine (2.57 ms per loop versus 829 µs per loop).

Comment: @ajcr I tried with a 100,000 row dataframe and the difference becomes 11.4ms vs. 8.9ms for my implementation versus yours. There is probably some battle/tradeoff between the vectorised `value_counts` and calling `apply`, there maybe a better way but I've not figured out a better way yet

Comment: @ajcr this gets closer to your version 8.91ms vx. 8.87ms : `df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.count(x.unique()))`

Comment: @EdChum Cool, thanks for posting these alternatives with timings; interesting to see how the different methods compare performance-wise.

Comment: Yes, it is very interesting and important for me too. Thank you for this discussion

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and [`.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
>>> df.groupby("A")["B"].nunique()
A
1    4
2    3
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: There is a built in `unique` attribute so it could be re-written like this: `df.groupby('A')['B'].unique().apply(lambda x: len(x))`